# Is it required to to send RTCP packet with RTP packet?

Tags: java, networking

I am working on a smartphone application. I have implemented SIP and SDP protocols. Now, for the audio part, do I have to send RTCP packet with RTP or can I leave the RTCP packet and keep sending and receiving the RTP packet?

Answer (score 2):

According to weikipedia *The primary function of RTCP is to provide feedback on the quality of service (QoS) in media distribution by periodically sending statistics information to participants in a streaming multimedia session.RTCP transports statistics for a media connection and information such as transmitted octet and packet counts, packet loss, packet delay variation, and round-trip delay time. An application may use this information to control quality of service parameters, perhaps by limiting flow, or using a different codec.*

It is up to you to implement it or not but if so many clients are going to connect to your application you should better use RTCP to manage bandwidth and QOS. Another usage of RTCP is for sending `Keep Alive` message to some devices such as webcams.

The answer in this question also explains another usage of RTCP.
[RTCP Transmission Intreval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033175/rtcp-transmission-intreval/22033588#22033588)